# slickgrid: visibility field in row

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible to have a field in my data array with the visibility status of each item and make slickgrid draw only the rows with visibility field true?

I have a large dataset and need to delete several items from my array and the delete operation is slow, but if I could mark the items as invisible, instead of delete, I think it will speed things up. I'm already using filters so I can't use a filter to hide the items...

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DataView, just create a filter that checks the "isDeleted" property and specify it in the DataView.

Comment: I use DataView but I already have other filters. I need to know the number of elements not deleted, and the number of actual elements returned by the other applied filters. can I create independent filters so I can get the number of not deleted, and the number of items filtered by the other filters?

Comment: You can't have multiple filters.
I don't really get why you can't just remove the deleted elements from the array and store them elsewhere while your are making your XHR request to delete them.

Comment: I am removing them from the array, but I have 200,000 rows, and need to be able to remove a variable number of rows, not sequential, from the array, so if I need to remove 100,000 I end up doing 100,000 splices and it takes time, specially with ie7. If I could only hide the rows, I think it would be much faster...

Comment: Just found a way of doing what I wanted without splice. End up adding a condition in the filter function to check if the item.isDeleted==true before the other filters.

Comment: 1) If you are removing 100'000 items from a 200'000-item array, don't use splice.  Create a new array and copy items on the fly.  Pick the implementation depending on the number of items being removed.
2) This is what I was suggesting in the first place.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand you suggestion at first.